# How to insert one character in front of a variable using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to turn this `input_variable = 1`
into `input_variable = 01`

From previous posts here I tried this but didn't work: 
`sed -e "s/\0" <<< "$input_variable"`

I get:

> Syntax error: redirection unexpected

What do I do wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT** 
Thanks to Benjamin I found a workaround (I would still like to know why the `sed` didn't work):

`new_variable="0$input_variable"`

Comment: are you reading the text `input_variable = 1` from file? If you have to change `1` to `01` always?

Comment: no not from file, `input_variable` is my variable that I want to add a `0` to

Comment: So you just want to prepend a zero to whatever the value of `input_variable` is? Any reason you can't just use `input_variable="0$input_variable"`?

Comment: yeahhhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!!!!! Awesomeeeeeeeeeeeee thanks! so easy, if you post it as an answer I'll aceept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be done with `sed`, simple assignment in your script can do exactly what you want done. For example, if you have `input_variable=1` and want `input_variable=01`, you can simply add a leading `0` by assignment:

```
input_variable="0${input_variable}"
```

or for additional types of numeric formatting you can use the `printf -v` option and take advantage of the *format-specifiers* provided by the `printf` function. For example:

```
printf -v input_variable "%02d" $input_variable
```

will *zero-pad* `input_variable` to a length of `2` (or any width you specify with the *field-width* modifier). You can also just add the leading zero regardless of the width with:

```
printf -v input_variable "0%s" $input_variable
```

`sed` is an excellent tool, but it isn't really the correct tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

You don't close the substitution command. Each substitution command must contain 3 delimiters

```
sed -e 's/pattern/replacement/' <<< 'text' # 3 backslashes
```

What you want to do could be done with:

```
sed -e 's/.*/0&/' <<< $input_variable
```

EDIT:

You are probably using Ubuntu and stumbled upon `dash` also known as the Almquist shell, which does not have the `<<<` redirection operator. The following would be a POSIX-compliant alternative, which works with `dash` as well:

```
sed -e 's/.*/0&/' <<~
$input_variable
~
```

And also this:

```
echo $input_variable | sed -e 's/.*/0&/'
```

---

To have the variable take on the new value, do this:

```
input_variable=$(echo $input_variable | sed -e 's/.*/0&/')
```

That's however not how you would write the shell script. Shell scripts usually give out some textual output, rather than setting external variables:

So, the script, let's call it *append_zero.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 | sed 's/.*/0&/'
```

and you would execute it like this:

```
$ input_variable=1
$ input_variable=$(append_zero.sh input_variable)
$ echo $input_variable
01
```

This way you have a working shell script that you can reuse with any Unix system that has a POSIX compliant /bin/sh

Comment: execute `echo $SHELL` in your shell and tell me the result as well as if you're using Ubuntu

Comment: I get `/bin/bash` and yes I am using ubuntu

Comment: Hmm, have you executed the `sed` command inside the shell itself or inside a script. The thing is that Ubuntu has installed `dash` as `/bin/sh`, which doesn't have the `<<<` redirection operator (which is not POSIX). See my edited answer

Comment: I run it inside a .sh script and in a if block. This `echo $input_variable | sed -e 's/.*/0&/'` works, however it doesn't store it

Comment: A thorough answer with great effort, but in choosing the correct tool for the job, calling a 3rd party utility to do what can be done with simple *assignment*, e.g. `input_variable="0${input_variable}"` probably deserves a note the shell provides the ability natively (all shells). `sed` is an excellent tool - for the right job.

Comment: I agree with you, however note that *using sed* is part of the question.